# AngularJS form validation print in snippet

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I am creating a form validation in `AngularJS` with bootstrap but the thing is that when someone hits the submit button the only action that i want in the form to do is to print the information in code snippet: For example the form will be

```
First Name: (input element)
Last Name: (input element)
Email: (input element)
```

And the result would be:

```
Your firstname is : John
Your lastname is : Doe
Your email is : john.Doe@johndoe.com
```

Thats it! Could you please help me on that?

For instance this example http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete but in Angularjs

Thanks a lot guyz

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to take a loot on Angular's documentation, as the [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive seems to be what you want.

In any case, you can do this on your HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="example()">
```

And then create that function on the controller that you're using.
Also for some complete form validation, check some projects like [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/).